# Get default value if key has falsy value in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, default

I am working in python, and was using `dict` in my code.

I have case where I always need `default` value if the give `key` is not exist or if `key` exists and it has `falsy` value.

for example

```
x = {'a': 'test', 'b': False, 'c': None, 'd': ''}
print x.get('a', [])
test
print x.get('b', []) # Need [] as False is falsy value in python
False 
print x.get('e', []) # This will work fine, because `e` is not valid key
None
print x.get('c', []) 
None
print x.get('c', []) or [] # This gives output which I want
```

Instead of check `Falsy` value in `or` operation, is there any pythonic way to get my default value?

Comment: It is pythonic; the alternative, if you want it to happen automatically, is to subclass dict and implement __getitem__.

Comment: I'd note that with `x.get('c', []) or []`, the first `[]` is not needed. Since it's falsey, you'll never return it, but rather use the second `[]` after the `or`. So just use `x.get('c') or []`.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght, but my example also required `notexistkey` in this case `c` is available, but if other key is not available then `.get('notexistkey', [])` will return value.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then.  `x.get('e', [])` will return `[]` not `None` as you're showing. And I can't tell what it is that you actually want from the two versions for key `'c'`. I'm assuming you want `[]`, but maybe not? My suggestion of `x.get(whatever) or []` should work the same as `x.get(whatever, []) or []` in all cases, it's just a little shorter and maybe a bit more Pythonic.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght i will use the second approach, thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `or` to *return* your default value is Pythonic. I'm not sure you will get a more *readable* workaround.

About using `or` in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

> This is a **short-circuit** operator, so it only evaluates the second
>   argument if the first one is False.

You must also consider that the value must have been accessed first before it can then be evaluated as *Falsy* or *Truthy*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ugly hack:

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = {'a': 'test', 'b': False, 'c': None, 'd': ''}
d = defaultdict(lambda : [], dict((k, v) if v is not None else (k, []) for k, v in x.items()))
print(d['a'])
# test
print(d['b'])
# False
print(d['e'])
# []
print(d['c']) 
# []
```